# ¿Por qué sale 'None' al hacer .reverse()?

Tags: python

Estoy practicando listas en python y me percaté de que si trato de hacer esto:

```
lista = [100,200,300,400,500]
print(lista.reverse())
```

y

```
salida = lista.reverse()
print(salida)
```

Ambos me dan como resultado en la consola: `None`. ¿Por qué ocurre esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como ya te comentaba Trauma, `list.remove` actúa in-place, es decir modifica el propio objeto en vez de retornar uno nuevo.

Esto es algo común a todos los métodos de objetos **mutables** como `dict`, `list`, `set`, etc destinados a modificar de alguna forma la estructura de datos, como insertar/eliminar items u ordenar. Estos métodos realizan la operación sobre su instancia y no retornan nada, En realidad, retornan `None` porque todo método/función en Python tiene siempre que retornar un objeto (y solo uno), y por defecto es `None`:

```
def funcion_que_no_hace_nada():
    ...

retorno = funcion_que_no_hace_nada()
print(retorno) #None
```

Puedes comprobar como el método realiza la operación `in-place`:

```
lista = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
lista.reverse()
print(lista) # [500, 400, 300, 200, 100]
```

Si por lo que sea quieres obtener una nueva lista dejando intacta la anterior, puedes hacer uso del builtin `reversed`:

```
lista = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
lista_invertida = list(reversed(lista))
print(lista)           # [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
print(lista_invertida) # [500, 400, 300, 200, 100]
```

`reversed` en este caso retorna un iterador y no una lista, lo cual es muy útil para iterar sobre la lista (u otro iterable) en orden inverso sin tener que modificarla o crear una copia de la misma:

```
for item in reversed(lista):
    print(item)
```

Presta siempre atención al nombre del método o función, observa:

- reverse (`list.reverse`) -> invertir (lista)
- reversed (`reversed(list)`) -> (lista) invertida

el nombre ya indica el tipo de acción que se realiza, la primera invierte la lista directamente y la segunda genera una nueva lista invertida (un iterador realmente) a partir de la dada.

Situaciones similares se dan con otros métodos, como el caso de `list.sort` y `sorted(list)`:

```
lista = [300, 200, 500, 400, 100]
lista.sort()
print(lista) # [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
```

---

```
lista = [300, 200, 500, 400, 100]
lista_ordenada = sorted(lista)
print(lista)          # [300, 200, 500, 400, 100]
print(lista_ordenada) # [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
```

Comment: Eres increíble! Sabes un montón! Muchas gracias!